# What's faster on ARM? MUL or (SHIFT + SUB)?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, assembly, arm

Which is faster on ARM?

```
*p++ = (*p >> 7) * 255;

or

*p++ = ((*p >> 7) << 8) - 1
```

Essentially what I'm doing here is taking an 8-bit word and setting it to 255 if >= 128, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: It's very likely the compiler will just convert the first form to the second.

Comment: Yes, you'd better first look into the assembly if they are really different. Otherwise, measuring would be the only way to know.

Comment: Building on what Jens said, just write the code the natural way and let the compiler choose which one is better. It will probably choose either way. If the mul is faster, it might even convert the latter form to the former. And most importantly, if which one is faster *changes* in the future, you won't have to change your code.

Comment: Which ARM, an ARMv4 core from 10 years ago, a tiny low power Cortex-M0, or a multi-issue pipelined out-of-order Cortex-A15?  There's no one answer.

Comment: The second version will always return 255 if *p is truly 8 bits. Shifting any 8 bits left by 8 bit positions (<< 8) will result in a byte value of zero. Subtract 1 and you get 255. See test2 in auselen's answer below.

Comment: @Variable Length Coder An ARM Cortex M0 with or without the single-cycle multiplication option?

Comment: Your two examples both have undefined behavior since the `*p++` and the `*p` do not have a sequence point between them.  A good compiler would warn you. [Converted my "answer" to a comment now that I have the ability.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `p` is `char` below statement is just an assignment to `255`.

`*p++ = ((*p >> 7) << 8) - 1`

If `p` is `int`, then of course it is a different story.

You can use [GCC Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22:3,%22filterAsm%22%3a%7B%22labels%22%3atrue,%22directives%22%3atrue,%22commentOnly%22%3atrue%7D,%22compilers%22%3a%5B%7B%22source%22%3a%22void%20test%28int%20%2ap%29%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%2ap++%20=%20%28%2ap%20%3E%3E%207%29%20%2a%20255;%5Cn%20%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnvoid%20test2%28int%20%2ap%29%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%2ap++%20=%20%28%28%2ap%20%3E%3E%207%29%20%3C%3C%208%29%20-%201%20;%5Cn%7D%22,%22compiler%22%3a%22/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.6%22,%22options%22%3a%22-O3%20-march=armv7-a%22%7D%5D%7D) to see how the assembly output looks like. Below is appearently what you get from `Linaro's arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ 4.6.3` with `-O2 -march=armv7-a` flags;

```
void test(char *p) {
  *p++ = (*p >> 7) * 255;

}

void test2(char *p) {
  *p++ = ((*p >> 7) << 8) - 1 ;
}

void test2_i(int *p) {
  *p++ = ((*p >> 7) << 8) - 1 ;
}

void test3(char *p) {
  *p++ = *p >= 128 ? ~0 : 0;
}

void test4(char *p) {
  *p++ = *p & 0x80 ? ~0 : 0; 
}
```

creates

```
test(char*):
    ldrb    r3, [r0, #0]    @ zero_extendqisi2
    sbfx    r3, r3, #7, #1
    strb    r3, [r0, #0]
    bx  lr
test2(char*):
    movs    r3, #255
    strb    r3, [r0, #0]
    bx  lr
test2_i(int*):
    ldr r3, [r0, #0]
    asrs    r3, r3, #7
    lsls    r3, r3, #8
    subs    r3, r3, #1
    str r3, [r0, #0]
    bx  lr
test3(char*):
    ldrsb   r3, [r0, #0]
    cmp r3, #0
    ite lt
    movlt   r3, #255
    movge   r3, #0
    strb    r3, [r0, #0]
    bx  lr
test4(char*):
    ldrsb   r3, [r0, #0]
    cmp r3, #0
    ite lt
    movlt   r3, #255
    movge   r3, #0
    strb    r3, [r0, #0]
    bx  lr
```

If you are not nitpicking best is always to check assembly of the generated code over such details. People tend to [overestimate compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_employment_theorem), I agree most of the time they do great but I guess it is anyone's right to question generated code.

You should also be careful interpreting instructions, since they won't always match into cycle accurate listing due to core's architectural featuers like having out-of-order, super scalar deep pipelines. So it might not be always shortest sequence of instructions win.

Comment: Great, thank you! What I took away from this is that test() is the most efficient, since it generates the fewest & fastest instructions and avoids branching. Yes, *p is an unsigned char.

Comment: @user1054922 if this is a call over some lengthly data (I hope so, since you are asking about some low level optimization) try to use a wider data type, like an int atleast - even better try to vectorize your code using neon instructions.

Comment: Yes, it's for image processing.. I'd like to do it as fast as possible without using processor-specific optimizations like NEON. I thought of using ints, but unless I'm mistaken, that's not possible without the data being vectorized to keep the 8-bit words 'bleeding' into eachother.

Comment: And `test2()` is the fastest, but generates wrong results.  The **ARM** uses an `unsigned char` by default.  Maybe [that point](http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/docs/faqs/signedchar.php) is lost on the OP?  I think `test3` and `test4` will be the fastest as false conditions execute in *zero cycles* on that CPU; unless the code is fetched from slow external memory.  Also, this looks like *thumb2* or at least unified assembler?

Comment: @artlessnoise I think OP now understand the problem in test2. Code I attached is result of objdump, in UAL format I believe, is that an issue?

Comment: @user1054922 I would read about XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378.

Comment: No problem with **UAL**, but you should note that `ite lt`, etc are just syntactic sugar and don't produce an op-code or any *cycles*.  I guess your overall point is none of them are probably the *best*.

Answer (score 3):

Well, to answer the question in your title, on ARM, a SHIFT+SUB can be done in a single instruction with 1 cycle latenency, while a MUL usually has multiple cycle latency.  So the shift will usually be faster.

To answer the implied question of what C code to write for this, generally you are best off with the simplest code that expresses your intent:

```
*p++ = *p >= 128 ? ~0 : 0;  // set byte to all ones iff >= 128
```

or

```
*p++ = *p & 0x80 ? ~0 : 0;  // set byte to all ones based on the MSB
```

this will generally get converted by the compiler into the fastest way of doing it, whether that is a shift and whatever, or a conditional move.

Comment: No, MUL is not _necessarily_ a multiple cycle instruction. On the Cortex-M3 architecture it is a single-cycle instruction for the simplest cases.

Comment: Many CPUs have cycle counts that depend on the multiplier size, so multiplying by a byte value can be significantly faster.  Also, instructions with a shift often take an extra cycle.  You have to look at the *technical reference manual*; and it will often depend on surrounding code.  A compiler will change the code depending on the targeted CPU.  The *fastest* code is probably one of the ARM bit test instructions and not anything the OP has guessed; your `C` code illuminates this.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact that your compiler can optimize the line quite well (and reading the assembly will tell you what is really done), you can refer from [this page](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0168a/i1000002.html) to know exactly how much cycles a MUL can take.

Comment: Note that this table applies only to the ARM9 architecture and not to all ARM processors or architectures.

Comment: @JoeHass There are other similar pages for other ARM architectures in the doc. The doc is organized by ARM architecture, so you will not find such a page for all architectures.

Comment: Minor correction: An ARM9 _processor_ would mean the ARMv4 or ARMv5 _architecture_.